# Using Javascript, how can I parse a JSON string containing a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm reading data using Javascript fetch from an Azure Table Storage, where one of the columns contain a JSON string.  So I'm getting back a string that I don't know how to format so that I can parse it.

> let jsonData =
>   '{"Timestamp":"2019-10-01T14:19:48.2593745+00:00","Data":"{\"app_id\":\"apple\",\"dev_id\":\"node1\",\"hardware_serial\":\"001122334455667788\",\"port\":1,\"counter\":63,\"payload_raw\":\"afIWk0ccABwM1Ag=\",\"payload_fields\":{\"doorState\":\"open\",\"humidity\":31,\"location\":{\"lat\":0,\"lon\":0},\"temperature\":22.6},\"metadata\":{\"time\":\"2019-10-01T14:19:48.009374928Z\",\"frequency\":867.9,\"modulation\":\"LORA\",\"data_rate\":\"SF7BW125\",\"coding_rate\":\"4/5\",\"gateways\":[{\"gtw_id\":\"banana\",\"gtw_trusted\":true,\"timestamp\":3579682692,\"time\":\"2019-10-01T14:19:47Z\",\"channel\":7,\"rssi\":-118,\"snr\":-5,\"rf_chain\":0,\"latitude\":0,\"longitude\":0,\"altitude\":172,\"location_source\":\"registry\"},{\"gtw_id\":\"banana\",\"timestamp\":567219172,\"time\":\"2019-10-01T14:19:47.98531Z\",\"channel\":7,\"rssi\":-55,\"snr\":10,\"rf_chain\":0,\"latitude\":0,\"longitude\":0,\"location_source\":\"registry\"}]},\"downlink_url\":\"https://www.someurl.com\"}"}';

After some testing I see that the escape backslashes cause problems, in addition to the quotation marks around the inner JSON object.

In short, parsing this fails:

```
let jsonData2 = '{"Test":"21342345","Data":"{\"test\":\"ethneipnrt\"}"}';
```

But this works:

```
let jsonData2 = '{"Test":"21342345","Data":{"test":"ethneipnrt"}}';
```

But how can I format the string automatically so that parsing works?

Comment: If possible you should fix the logic that generates this data. If not, then you simply have to call `JSON.parse` again. Eg. `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(jsonData2).Data)`.

Comment: @FelixKling I believe the issue is that the original `JSON.parse` returns an invalid JSON string (it includes backslashes).

Comment: @TylerRoper Yes, I think you're right.  It fails already on the first JSON.parse, so as far as I can see the second JSON.parse is never run.

Comment: Really depends on the context. `{"Test":"21342345","Data":"{\"test\":\"ethneipnrt\"}"}` is valid JSON. Now if you put this into a JavaScript **string literal** you will get invalid JSON since the `\"` become `"`.   Having said that, there really is no reason to write (or generate) JavaScript code that includes a string literal containing JSON. How are you getting the JSON?

Comment: The data is sensor values pushed from The Things Network to a function in Azure that stores the data in a Storage Table.  It's then read using fetch from a REST API.  So the actual string is an array of the data strings above, like this: `[{"Test":"21342345","Data":"{\"test\":\"ethneipnrt\"}"},{"Test":"21342345","Data":"{\"test\":\"ethneipnrt\"}"},{"Test":"21342345","Data":"{\"test\":\"ethneipnrt\"}"}]`

Comment: If you are getting the string via an XHR, then it should work as expected. It's valid JSON as you can verify here: https://jsonlint.com/. It just wouldn't work if you put it in a string literal as you do in your example. But as I said, ideally the system that generates the data would not double encode it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I got the parsing to work yesterday by filtering away the unwanted elements.  First replacing all instances of '"{' with '{', then replacing all instances of '}"' with '}', and finally removing all backslashes.

```
let data = jsonData.replace(/"{/g, '{').replace(/}"/g, '}').replace(/\\/g, '');
let parsed = JSON.parse(data);
```

I agree that this should probably be handled in the backend.  But for now it's enough to get the page up and running.